# Confused about connect function of Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just took over a legacy code which written in `React` and `Redux`. I'm very confused about the usage of `connect` function, as follows:

```
export default connect(state => state)(Root);
```

I searched all of the code, but I could not find the state variable.
The **App.js** as following:

```
class Root extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.field = new Field(this);
    this.state = {
      userName: 'Tom'
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(actions.getUserName({id:1001},(x)=>{console.log(x)}))
  }
  render() {
    const { userName } = this.state;
    const { userData } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>hello {userData} </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(state => state)(Root);
```

The **Actions.js** as following:

```
export const GET_USER_NAME = ns('GET_USER_NAME');

export function getUserName(arg, callback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axiosClient.fetch({
      api: '/getUserNameById',
      data: arg
    }).then((user) => {
        callback(user.name)
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USER_NAME,
          data: user.name
        });
      })
  };
}
```

The **reducer.js** as following:

```
import * as actions from '../actions/index'
const initialState = {
};
const defaultAction = {
  type: 'doNothing',
};

export default function index(state = initialState, action = defaultAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.GET_USER_NAME:
      return { ...state, userData: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Store.js** as:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
const createStoreWithMdware = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore);
export default createStoreWithMdware;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature from `connect` is

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

So this weird sintax

```
connect(state => state)(Root)
```

Is the equivalent of

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state

connect(mapStateToProps, undefined)(Root)
```

`state` is provided by redux to `mapStateToProps`. Is a snapshot of your store's state. `state => state` means: "Serialize all my state into `Root` `props`".

Usually we use `state` to serialize just a part of it into our components, something like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ foo : state.foo })
```

Comment: Are the first state and the second state the same thing?

Comment: it's a function which receives `state` and returns `state`. Same thing as `function mapStateToProps(state){ return state }`

Answer (score 1):

connect is a higher order component which accepts two parameters `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, where `mapStateToProps` makes redux store values available as props to the component and `mapDispatchToProps` makes redux actions available as props to the component.

Here, 
`connect(state => state)` means that all the redux store keys are mapped to props to the component. So, lets say if your redux store looks like this:

```
{
  home: { count: 1 },
  login: { isLoggedIn: true }
}
```

then,

on doing `connect(state => state)`, the component props will be,

```
{
  ...originalProps,
  home: { count: 1 },
  login: { isLoggedIn: true }
}
```

If you want to use only `isLoggedIn` in your component then you can only map that to props by:

```
connect( state =>({
  isLoggedIn: state.login.isLoggedIn
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Redux `connect` function allows you to *connect* a component to the app-wise Redux store. Once connected, your component can receive part of the Redux store current state as props (or the whole state, like in your case).

In this line

```
export default connect(state => state)(Root);
```

two things happen.
**First**: the first call to connect takes a function as the first argument. This function, usually referred to as `mapStateToProps`, allow you to define which properties of the Redux store you need to make available to your component, and under which name. In your case, your function return the whole store, as-is, so your component will have in its props all the properties of the store.
**Second**: the second call, is what is usually called an HOC (High Order Component), a function that returns a React Component. Its argument is the component to be connected. This component will be wrapped and will receive the props specified in the first function call.

```
const addSomePropsFromReduxStoreTo = connect(state => state)
const connectedRoot = addSomePropsFromReduxStoreTo(Root)
```

Redux will also add a special extra prop, `dispatch`, that allows you to *dispatch* an action and, through it, to update the Redux store state. That is why, in your Root's `componentDidMount` method you can do:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(actions.getUserName({id:1001},(x)=>{console.log(x)}))
  }
```

If you are curious about where the state is, it is defined in your Store.js file (with the function `createStore`). In the root component of your app (usually App.js), you should have a special component, called **Provider** that takes the store as a prop. Thanks to this special component at the root of your app, every descendant component is able to *connect* itself and access the store.